# Determine a basis for all vectors $(a,b,c)$ where $ b=a+c$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> All vectors of the form $(a,b,c)$, where $b = a + c$

So in this one we have
$$ 
\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} a \\ a + c \\ c \end{bmatrix}= a\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} +
c \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
therefore, a bases would be the set $\{v_1, v_2\}$ where:
$$v_1=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, \quad
v_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
Any complaints?

Comment: So, how many of these questions are you going to ask?

Comment: That question was the odd number in the book, it had four parts. The first one I didn't actually ask. I started from the second part. I'm now onto the next question which is even and has the answers in the book. So you will have to wait a while now for the next one, sorry @Gerry, hehehe.

Comment: Good. ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer seems fine to me. ${}$

Comment: Thanks @Shaun. I will accept this when the count-down ends. Cheers.

Comment: You're welcome, @Bucephalus.